# Job listing offering INR 7-30(USD 0.106- 0.45)

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I came across a [job listing](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/107680/big-data-technical-leads-architects-datametica-solutions-pvt-ltd?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=large-sidebar-blue-looking) on my homepage, which offers INR 7-30(USD 0.106- 0.45).

Considering that the listing is for a senior dev role with desired experience of 10 years, and you can't even buy a decent cup of tea with INR 7 in India, I believe this to be a bug.

Should raising the issue on meta be enough or should I also flag this as a problem through the option in the listing itself?

Comment: More likely a typo than a "bug".

Comment: Is it not implicit that it is "lakh" in India?  Well, sure it is.

Comment: @HansPassant all the job listings for companies based out of India, here on SO actually mention it clearly. For ex:[this](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/109757/senior-lead-developer-at-a-profitable-saas-startup-recruiterbox?offset=10&distanceunits=Km&location=Banglore&range=20) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/110219/polyglot-developer-ruby-javascript-python-mavenhive-technologies-pvt-ltd?offset=10&distanceunits=Km&location=Banglore&range=20), hence this particular listing comes out as weird.

Comment: Indeed looks like a bug. Someone looking to pay you 0.45 USD a year would be ridiculous.

Comment: Last time I checked, INR 4 buys you a decent cup of tea. Prices may have increased though.

Comment: Maybe it's INR 7-30 per minute. That's a fscking boatload of tea.

Comment: @oulenz nope. A decent cup of tea is at least ₹25.

Comment: Assume people say what they mean. The ad says (in effect), "We want to hire someone stupid enough to work for 10 cents a year". Now - ask yourself if you're qualified. :-)

Comment: I came here because it looked like an interesting question - now I just want a cup of tea. I'm confused.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Thanks for your report!

I flagged the listing for review, someone from sales support is going to look into it shortly.

If you encounter a suspicious job in the future, you can use the [image: teh button] link in the sidebar.